# How do I get Adobe Camera RAW to read the the in-camera settings from Nikon raw .NEF files?

Tags: nikon, raw, photoshop, metadata

I dislike the losing of camera settings when I shoot in raw (.NEF) in nikon. The colors become dimmed and the camera noise reduction is removed , so the the photos look very noisy compared with relative .jpg direct photos.

I have tried to open RAW files of canon in photoshop , and I was able to get the camera settings to be applied on the raw files, but I couldn't do that in nikon raw files.
is there are any software or plugins for PS or lightroom to do that?

Comment: What version of Photoshop are you using?

Comment: I am using CS4 , and I have tried previous versions of course .

Answer (score 3):

If you're using a more recent version (I can't say for pre-CS4), the Adobe Camera Raw processor has a tab in the settings box for camera profiles. You should be able to select from several different profiles which are designed to mimic the behaviour of the vendor's development process, at least for Canon and Nikon (us Pentaxians don't have as many options as I understand).

Anyways, downloading a sample NEF image for a D300, I got options for Camera D2X Mode 1 through 3, Camera Landscape, Camera Neutral, Camera Portrait, Camera Standard, Camera Vivid along with standard Adobe profiles for ACR 6.1. I have a feeling the one that you want is either Standard or Vivid, the Vivid really pops the colours, but experimentation is half the fun.

On a side note, the funny thing about the sample image I got is that it's a picture of a Pentax booth!

Comment: do you mean camera calibration tab, then camera profiles ?
I have tried it, but found only pre settings like portrait and landscape, but did not find profiles for cameras . is it possible to add or configure profile for my camera to be added to this list ?

Comment: @ess Check for updates for Photoshop. However, if you saw portrait or landscape, they're specific to your camera model.

Answer (score 0):

Nikon's own RAW processing software ([CaptureNX](http://www.capturenx.com/en/index.html)) will probably get you the most in-camera like results.

Alternatively, shoot both RAW and JPG.

Comment: but what about photoshop and lightroom ? 
why canon raw files in-camera settings is retrievable while nikon are not ?

Comment: I'd like to know how this works for you in case of Canon camera. I get radically different results from Canon's own software and other converters.

Comment: Camera profiles are not something that come from the camera. They are just profiles created by Adobe that are matched to the profiles of the canon firmware. Same goes for all other camera profiles...they are only approximations. There is no guarantee that the settings applied by a camera profile in ACR/Lightroom will exactly match that from a Nikon or Canon camera body.

Comment: @jrista - that was meant to the other answer?

Comment: No, it was meant for this answer and your comment. You mentioned getting different results in different software. Its just because no software can exactly replicate what the firmware does, as its all dependent upon what bit depth the algorithm works in, and the specifics and precision of the tone curves applied.

Answer (score 0):

While there is a colour profile selection in ACR which mimics the manufacturers profile no settings will be picked up from RAW file and be reapplied to make the photo in editor look similar to JPEG of camera. It happens so because manufacturer settings are often too special and follow no standard. While being technically possible it is rarely required by photographers because in-camera JPEG look is not of great value in most cases.

DNG format includes a number of operations for processing which camera may specify for a RAW file - distortion and CA correction, colour profile, tonal curve but it still is up to OEM to write a DNG which will give image similar to JPEG.

> How do I get Adobe Camera RAW to read the the in-camera settings from Nikon raw .NEF files?

There is no way.